# How did Jyn manage to keep her necklace from the Empire?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

In *Rogue One*, we see Jyn's mother kneeling next to her and giving her a necklace and saying "trust the force." We later find that Jyn has been imprisoned by the Empire for years and then rescued again by the Rebellion. Only a little while after that, we find out that Jyn *still* has the necklace, despite having been captured and thrown in a cell.

What I'm wondering is, how did Jyn keep the necklace from the prying eyes of the Empire? For comparison, the Nazis would have their prisoners hand over every valuable on their body, and then would have them go through inspection again several times before and when they reached the concentration camps. Although it is assuming a lot to say the Empire did the same, how was Jyn able to keep it from them?

Comment: As it stands, this might be opinion-based.  It might work better to ask (if we know) how Jyn managed to hang onto the necklace.  By your example, concentration camp survivors did manage to hang onto a few things, as did POWs.

Comment: As bad as the Empire was, there's no evidence that they were routinely running extermination camps.  And if you're imprisoning people for crimes that you expect to eventually release them for then letting them keep their trinkets helps preserve an appearance that the Empire is a force for order, not chaos.  (Which was basically the gist of their PR.)

Comment: You think they funded the Death Star by selling second-hand jewellery on space eBay?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

She 'smuggled it into the prison'. History doesn't record how she managed this, but some things are better [left to the imagination](https://getyarn.io/yarn-clip/1593e8fa-0bd1-4b99-8ebb-000152f247ff).

> Neither of them spoke again. Jyn lay on her slab and didn’t sleep and
> toyed with the necklace tucked under her shirt—the crystal she’d
> managed to keep, smuggled into the prison when she should have been
> worried about weapons or a comlink. She didn’t think much about her
> would-be murderer, knowing that if Kennel didn’t kill her something
> else would.
>
> <sub><sup>[Rogue One: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Rogue_One:_A_Star_Wars_Story)</sup></sub>